# Wrong model type but no model was passed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view `"_Initial"` with the model: `@model Release`

In the main view I have:

```
@if (Model == null || Model.Release == null)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Initial")//error here
}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("_Initial", Model.Release)
}
```

The main view has the model: `@model WorkspaceData` and I can't phantom why am I getting the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WNCT_Web_Application.BL.Workspace.Monitoring.WorkspaceData', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WNCT_Web_Application.BL.Release.Release'.

When I'm not even sending a model (the partial view has logic for when the model is null)?

Answer (score 4):

By default if you do not specify a model, or the model you are passing is `null`, then `Html.Partial` uses the model from `ViewDataDictionary` (in your case `WorkspaceData`. To overcome this, you can pass a new instance of `Release` to the partial

```
@Html.Partial("_Initial", new WNCT_Web_Application.BL.Release.Release())
```

Comment: No, I must pass `null`.

Comment: As you have discovered from the duplicate you can pass `new ViewDataDictionary()` but this suggests you have a (minor) design flaw. Any HtmlHelper in the partial view will internally throw an exception (its all handled gracefully of course) which is why you should always avoid passing a null model. It would be better to check for (say) a default `ID` property - `if (model.ID == 0)` or `if (model.ID == null)`

Comment: Do the internal exceptions affect performance?

Comment: Yes, just as any exception is, but it minor. Just wanted to make you aware that its better to pass a model if possible (just as you should always use `return View(model)` instead of `return View()` in a controller method)

Comment: And only if the view has no model type defined I must use `return View()`?

Comment: You can still use `return View()` even of a model is defined (say in a 'Create' method), its just that its better to initialize a new instance of your model and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You have a design issue here. Rather than one partial view named `_Initial`, it looks like you need two partials views

- One to use when Model or Model.Release is null
- One to use when Model.Release is not null

For example:

```
@if (Model == null || Model.Release == null)
{
    @Html.Partial("_InitialNullRelease")
}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("_Initial", Model.Release)
}
```

Obviously you can choose a better name than what I've given.

Depending on how complicated `_Initial` actually is, or what's it's meant to do, splitting the view into two might be a good approach.

Comment: `_Initial` isn't complex, it just makes some checks with the `Release` sent and the releases in the application to color code it red in the UI if it was deleted from the application. I don't think I should create 2 views since it will only duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `Html.Partial("_Initial", null, new ViewDataDictionary())`

Thanks **Stephen Muecke** for telling me about `ViewDataDictionary` and how it sends the model of the view to the partial if no model was given to the `Html.Partial`method.